# Iterate Values of a dataSnapshot.value hashmap from a Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, hashmap

I'm creating a "Virtual Garage App" for motorcycles, and I can't retrieve the data from my Firebase, I can only access the HashMap of each motorcycle in database.
This is my database content:

[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKeUD.png)

Here is my code where I try to retrieve the data:
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8g4wa.png)

Here is the `ExampleItem()` object where I try to place the data: [ExampleItem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTQz4.png)

Is there any way to iterate through the values of the dataSnapshot.value HashMap in order to call the setters for each string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to iterate through the values of the dataSnapshot.value HashMap in order to call the setters for each string?

You can get it even simpler, by accessing the exact property you need. For example, to display the value of "motoBrand" property, please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference mototrackRef = rootRef.child("mototrack");
    mototrackRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                String motoBrand = ds.child("motoBrand").getValue(String.class);
                Log.d("TAG", motoBrand);
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

In the exact same way you can get the value of the other properties. In kotlin will look like this:

```
val rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
val mototrackRef = rootRef.child("mototrack")
mototrackRef.get().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
    if (task.isSuccessful) {
        for (ds in task.result.getChildren()) {
            val motoBrand = ds.child("motoBrand").getValue(String::class.java)
            Log.d("TAG", motoBrand)
        }
    } else {
        Log.d("TAG", task.exception.getMessage()) //Don't ignore potential errors!
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried your code and it retrieves the correct values, but I don't understand why it doesn't add them to the object with the setter. Here is my code: https://imgur.com/a/AvRS6g4

Comment: Nvm, it worked, thank you very much ! Apparently setters don't work how I expected them to work.

Comment: Good to hear that it worked and you get the correct values. The setters are setting data, doesn't return something.